# Wkhtmltopdf version for Cloud Linux

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, wkhtmltopdf-binary

I have CloudLinux release 7.6 in my server and I used to have wkhtmltopdf linux generic version 0.12.4 previously. I am trying to upgrade wkhtmltopdf to version 0.12.5 and I noticed they no longer have generic linux version.

1. How do I install the latest version of wkhtmltopdf in my server that uses CloudLinux?
2. Can I safely install and use the 0.12.5 version for CentOS 7 instead or is my only option is to continue using the 0.12.4 generic linux version on CloudLinux?

Comment: CloudLinux is based on CentOS I think, so it ought to just work. (In general anything based on CentOS is aiming to be RHEL-compatible, so they should be compatible with each other too.) Try installing the package and see if there are any dependency errors, or if it just works? Or you can always build it from source, or take the source RPM for the 0.12.5 CentOS build and build that.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same too since both are RHEL. I will try to give it go. I have to release my production server in 1 day so dont have much time to do extensive test. I will first install the CentOS 7 version of this binary and see if it just runs on CloudLinux. Thanks for sharing your comment @Rup

Comment: It might be safest to stick with 0.12.4 then if that's what you've done all your testing with so far, unless you definitely need to upgrade? But I expect the CentOS version will be fine.

Comment: Hi @Rup, I just now did an upgrade to 0.12.5 version using the CentOS build in my cloud linux and it seems to be working fine. I did `wget` and then `rpm -Uvh  wkhtmltox-0.12.5-1.centos7.x86_64.rpm` which installed the binaries in `/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf`. I updated the binaries path in my app and it seems to work fine. I will see how this goes and if I have issues in the future, I will revert back to the generic version. But so far so good.

Comment: I am on the process of migrating to a bigger server and I thought of updating the binary while I am installing the services in my new server. Thank you for your support since it gave me the confidence to give it a try. If you post it as the answer, I will gladly accept it. Thank you @Rup

Comment: Thanks, but "it'll probably work" isn't really an answer. If you've tested it and it does work, then you should post that.

Comment: Fair enough. Will do after running it for couple of days to make sure. Thank heaps @Rup I do appreciate your response indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed the CentOS 7 build version of Wkhtmltopdf in my CloudLinux Release 7 and its works fine. I have been using it in my production server for a week now and havent had any issues. Since CentOS and CloudLinux are RHEL compatible, it works fine.

I installed the binaries like this:

```
$ wget https://downloads.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12/0.12.5/wkhtmltox-0.12.5-1.centos7.x86_64.rpm
$ rpm -Uvh  wkhtmltox-0.12.5-1.centos7.x86_64.rpm
$ which wkhtmltopdf
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

Thanks to @Rup in comments who helped me with this.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are using Cloud Linux and need to install the latest version (now 12.6) - you might get dependancy errors using the above method.

I used:

```
yum install -y https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox-0.12.6-1.centos7.x86_64.rpm
```

Based on suggestion by [ashkulz on Github](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/4263)